# Chrome Remote Desktop with android

Tags: google-chrome, android, remote-desktop

I have a dream that one day I can remotely connect to my Ubuntu using my android(remote desktop)...

On a more serious note I have tried many solutions for doing that , lastly I have tried the chrome remote chrome desktop plug-in . I installed the extension and the package (chrome-remote-desktop_current_amd64.deb
) with a debain pacakge installer. I added the following line :

```
exec /usr/sbin/lightdm-session "gnome-session --session=ubuntu"
```

in a file(.chrome-remote-desktop-session) that  I created in the home directory . Then I  installed the app for android ,pressed on get started and enabled remote-connections and entered the pin. Now in the android app i can see my computer however it is grayed out and when I click it says "Host is offline". Where did i go wrong ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Did you tried [Chrome Remote Desktop](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.chromeremotedesktop)?

Answer (score 0):

Send mashee a dream that one day I can remotely connect to my Ubuntu using my android(remote desktop)...

On a more serious note I have tried many solutions for doing that , lastly I have tried the chrome remote chrome desktop plug-in . I installed the extension and the package (chrome-remote-desktop_current_amd64.deb ) with a debain pacakge installer. I added the following line :

exec /usr/sbin/lightdm-session "gnome-session --session=ubuntu"
in a file(.chrome-remote-desktop-session) that I created in the home directory . Then I installed the app for android ,pressed on get started and enabled remote-connections and entered the pin. Now in the android app i can see my computer however it is grayed